# Python: check if n elements in a list exist in a string; middle ground between any() and all()?

Tags: python

I have a list containing 10 keywords/phrases. If a string is inputted into some function and any 8 of these terms appear in the inputted string, I want the function to output True, and False otherwise. My current implementation looks like this:

```
score = 0
for term in keywords:
    if term in string:
        score += 1

if score >= 8:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

I'm positive there is a more elegant way to implement this. Is there a built-in function that handles this kind of logic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
return sum(term in string for term in keywords) >= 8
```

The slight bit of magic here is treating True and False as 1 and 0--that's why we can `sum()` a sequence of bools to count the True values.

Comment: in theory, there must be some way to construct a regex and do the search with one pass through the string instead of `len(keywords)` passes... but it's going to be more lines of code and probably harder to understand, so not worth it unless this is a performance bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Or:

```
c=0
for i in keywords:
    if i in string:
        c+=1
return c>=8
```

Comment: @DownVoter i think i am down-voted because it's a for loop inefficient

Comment: I don't think this improves anything, on the contrary, it's less readable than the OP's version.